# Windows forms - display image in gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I have to display an image in a `GridView` cell.

For example, let 'Stock' be a column in a `GridView`.

In that column, based on the condition, I have to display either an image or text. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 : Add your image in Resources.resx under properties folder. (ex. Picture1.jpeg)
Step 2 : Add a DataGridViewImageColumn in your DataGridView
Step 3 : Add image this way

```
for (int row = 0; row <= [YourDataGridViewName].Rows.Count - 1; row++)
{
    ((DataGridViewImageCell)gvFiles.Rows[row].Cells[1]).Value = Properties.Resources.Picture1
}
```

that's it

Manoj

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean `DataGridView` as `GridView` is a control in ASP.NET not Winforms.

And to answer your question: yes it is possible.

If you have `DataGridViewImageColumn` and want to show inside text you have to create textbox cell and replace it with default cell in that column:

```
var row = new DataGridViewRow();
row.Cells[Stock.Index] = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
row.Cells[Stock.Index].Value = "Test";
```

Comment: no, its a windows application gridview control. If DB return value is 'NULL', then i need to display an image else i need to to display the returned text in the same column.

Comment: I don't see any control named `GridView` for Winforms but some custom control made by Telerik - is that what you are using?